# Warning: Invalid DOM property `for`. Did you mean `htmlFor`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach

El aviso de advertencia :

> Warning: Invalid DOM property `for`. Did you mean `htmlFor`?

Me aparece al ejecutar la siguiente función:

```
listarPermisos(permisos){
    var myarra=[];
    if(permisos != undefined ){
        for(var obj in permisos){
            myarra.push(
                    <OnePermission
                        key={obj}
                        titulo={obj}
                        lista={permisos[obj]}
                        onChangePermission={this.onChangePermission}
                    />);
        }
    }else{
        console.log("Permisos no encontrados")
    }
    return myarra;
}
```

Aunque todo funciona sin problemas, me causa molestias al verlo en la consola del navegador. EL objeto que deseo recorrer es el siguiente:`permisos`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dicho `array` tiende a crecer según vaya el avance del proyecto, razón por la cual lo recorro con un `for`.

> ¿Como recorrer las propiedades de un objeto con javascript-reactjs?

**EDICION**

Clase-component: **OnePermission**

```
const OnePermission = ({titulo,lista,onChangePermission})=>{
    return (
        <div className="group_role" style={{display:"flex",flexDirection:"column",paddingBottom:"15px"}}>
            <div style={{padding:"5px 12px 5px"}}>
            <h2>{titulo}</h2>
            </div>
            <div style={{display:"flex",flexWrap:"wrap"}}>
            {
                lista.map((el)=>(
                    <div key={el.id} className="mycheckbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name={`check${el.id}`} id={`check${el.id}`} checked={el.check}  onChange={(e)=>onChangePermission(e,titulo,el.id)}/>
                        <label for={`check${el.id}`}>{el.display_name}</label>
                    </div>
                ))
            }
            </div>
        </div>
        )
}
```

EL resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si estas usando algun label tienes que usar `htmlFor` en lugar de `for`, ya que `for` es una palabra reservada. Solo que en el codigo que compartes no miro que uses un label

Comment: mostranos como esta compuesto el componente `<OnePermission />` estimo que ahi esta el elemento que reporta la advertencia.

Comment: @JuanMarco, Edite la pregunta y mostre el codigo de `OnePermission`

Comment: Genial, reemplazar `for` por [`htmlFor`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#htmlfor) resuelve el problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplemente es cambiar el `for` a `htmlFor` en la etiqueta label:

**De esto**

```
<label for={`check${el.id}`}>{el.display_name}</label>
```

**A esto**

```
<label htmlFor={`check${el.id}`}>{el.display_name}</label>
```

Comment: Joder que novatada la mia. gracias.