# React.js - Comportamiento inesperado en bucle for

Tags: reactjs

Estoy construyendo un componente que se encarga de subir fotos al servidor. Le agregué una funcionalidad donde el usuario, mientras ingresa sus fotos, tiene una vista previa de éstas y puede descartar una foto seleccionada. El problema con el que me topé es el siguiente: por cada foto eliminada ejecuto una animación, pero noté que la animación no se ejecuta siempre, diría que lo hace el 70% de los casos. Aveces menos, aveces más.
El código es el siguiente:

```
class photos extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            photosPreView : [],  //Aquí habrá una lista de URL para mostrar en pantalla
            files: []  //Aquí habrá una lista de archivos (fotos) que serán luego enviadas
        }
    }

    handleFileChange = (event) => {
        if(event.target.files[0]){
            var newPhotoPreView = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
            var newFile = event.target.files[0];
            this.setState({
                photosPreView : [...this.state.photosPreView , newPhotoPreView ], //Lista de URLs (vistas previas actuales)
                files: [...this.state.files, newFile ]                            //Lista de fotos (lo que se va a mandar al servidor)
            })
        }
    }

    deleteOnePreView = (event) => {
        if(window.confirm('Vas a eliminar esta foto, ¿estás seguro?')){
            for(let i = 0 ; i < this.state.photosPreView.length ; i++){   //Cantidad de fotos actuales en la vista previa
                if(event.target.src === this.state.photosPreView[i]){    //Identifico cada foto por su índice dentro del array, ya que no posee "_id" propio
                    event.target.style.animation = "delete .3s";    //Luego de encontrar el índice de la vista previa, ejecuto la animación de borrado (es un transform scale de 1 a 0)
                    setTimeout( () => {     //Espero .3s y luego cambio el estado
                        this.setState({
                            photosPreView : this.state.photosPreView.filter(newPreView => newPreView !== this.state.photosPreView[i] ),
                            files: this.state.files.filter( newFile => newFile !== this.state.files[i])})
                    }, 300);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <input type="file" onChange={this.handleFileChange}></input>
                {this.state.photosPreView.map((photo, index) => 
                    <img src={photo} key={index} onClick={this.deleteOnePreView} //Este es el evento donde se ejecuta la animación
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Quizás no sea la mejor forma de escribir código, pero soy nuevo en React (en realidad en la programación en sí) y voy aprendiendo sobre la marcha. Si tienen, a parte de una respuesta con la solución a mi problema, sugerencias para optimizar mi código serán muy bien recibidas.

Comment: En tu timeout tienes 300, serían 3000 para los 3 segundos. Estas cambiando el estado dentro del bucle de tiempo, no lo se a ciencia cierta pero puede desencadenar un montón de cambios en tu componente y provocar cierta inestabilidad... Si solo necesitas hacerlo una vez después de tres segundos ponlo a después del temporizador, no dentro..

Comment: Sí, estoy utilizando 300, cuando ejecuto la animación le digo "event.target.style.animation = "delete .3s" (o sea, 0.3s).
No sabía que genera conflictos cambiar el estado dentro del timeout, ¿eso a qué se debe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero algunos consejos.

**1ro.-** En `React.js` siempre debes pensar en todo como un **Estado** y un **Componente**, ten en cuenta eso.

**2do.-** Trata de evitar, siempre que se pueda utilizar ciclos como el `for`, `foreach` o `while`, nativos de javascript.

**3ro.-** Leé sobre [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array)s de javascript para mejorar en react.

Dicho esto paso a dar una solucion posible:

Entonces de acuerdo al primer consejo la siguiente linea esta mal (vista por react, en javascript esta super bien):

```
 event.target.style.animation = "delete .3s";
```

debes de crear un `state` para cambiar el `style` de tu imagen seleccionada para lo cual debes de modificar `photosPreView` a un array de objetos, uno similar a este:

```
{
    url:"url_de_image.png",
    style:{animation:""}
}
```

Posteriormente intenta no utilizar `for`, intenta lo siguiente

```
deleteOnePreView = (event) => {
        if(window.confirm('Vas a eliminar esta foto, ¿estás seguro?')){
            var aux= [...this.state.photosPreView]; 
            var files=[...this.state.files]; 
            var indice_buscado=aux.findIndex((el)=>event.target.src === this.state.photosPreView.url);//buscamos el indice del objeto
            aux[indice_buscado].style={animation:"delete .3s"};
            this.setState({
                photosPreView:aux
            })
            setTimeout( () => {     
                    aux.splice(indice_buscado,1);//splice elimina/actualiza el elemento en el indice indicado
                    files.splice(indice_buscado,1);
                    this.setState({
                        photosPreView : aux,
                        files: files
                    })
            }, 300)//esto no es necesario si en realidad envias la imagen a un servidor

        }
    }
```

Y en tu render modificar:

```
{
    this.state.photosPreView.map((photo, index) => 
    <img src={photo.url} style={photo.style} key={index} onClick={this.deleteOnePreView} />)
}
```

Esa es la idea aun no lo prove asi que todo depende de ti.

**EDICION**

`findIndex` retorna un entero que representa el indice de la primera coincidencia encontrada, si el elemento no es encontrado retorna -1.

`setTimeout`, al final `react.js` es javasscript ó todo el codigo lo "complila" a javascript puro, lo cual no veo ningun problema en llamar a `setState` dentro del mismo.

Lo del `for`, hace unos dias me hice la misma pregunta, dicen que es una palabra reservada... pero no encontré una respuesta concreta, solo hay que evitar su uso lo mas posible.

Te dejo el link de mi pregunta:[Warning: Invalid DOM property `for`. Did you mean `htmlFor`?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/339350/warning-invalid-dom-property-for-did-you-mean-htmlfor)

Una idea mas. podrias reducir mas tu codigo si dejas de manejar `files` y a este lo incluyes en `photosPreView`, asi utilizas un solo array para todo.

```
{
    url:"url_de_image.png",
    style:{animation:""},
    files:null
}
```

Comment: No conocía el método `findIndex`, ¿retorna un entero?, ¿devuelve el índice del elemento que cumplió con la condición?.
Leí en uno de los comentarios que está mal hacer un `setState` dentro de un `setTimeout`, ¿es verdad?
¿Por qué evitar buques `for`, `forEach` y `while`?
Respecto a tu solución, muchísimas gracias, voy a probarla y al finalizar te comento qué pasó.

Comment: @BrianHerrera, saludos, edite la respuesta espero te sirva.

Comment: Haciendo que cada elemento tenga el estado `style = {animation: ""}` las animaciones se ejecutan siempre, ya no hay elementos que no responden, ¡es genial!.. He aprendido algo nuevo, voy a implementarlo de ahora en adelante. Muchísimas gracias por el tiempo invertido, me sirvió de mucho.
Por cierto, vi tu post pero no puedo comentar; el warning `htmlFor` no aparece por usar el bucle for, sino porque en tus label utilizas el atributo `for`, que en react se debería llamar `htmlFor`. Quizás seguramente ya lo sabías, pero por las dudas te lo comento.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias cosas raras, por ejemplo, no entiendo la necesidad del for cuando solo necesitas obtener la preview que hace match. Además, en lugar de un `timeout` puedes hacerlo mediante el evento `transitionend`.

```
/**
 * Clona la lista de objetos (photosPreView)
 * exceptuando al objeto a eliminar
 * @param {object} photoToRemove Preview a eliminar
 */
getPhotosPreviewsExcept = (photoToRemove) => {
  const newData = this.state.photosPreView.filter(
    photo => photo.src !== photoToRemove.src
  ).map(photo => {
    return Object.assign({}, photo);
  });
  return newData;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param {MouseEvent} event
 */
deleteOnePreView = (event) => {
  if (window.confirm('Vas a eliminar esta foto, ¿estás seguro?')) {
    const { target } = event;
    // obtiene la preview a eliminar
    const photoToRemove = this.state.photosPreView.find(photo => photo === target.src);
    // añade el listener para cuando termine la animación (delete)
    photoToRemove.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
      this.setState({
        photosPreView: getPhotosPreviewsExcept(photoToRemove)
      });
    });
    // añde la clase de animación
    photoToRemove.style.animation = 'delete 300ms';
  }
}
```

Para evitar buscar la imagen, puedes modificar tu render de esta manera:

```
{this.state.photosPreView.map((photo, index) => 
  <img src={photo} key={index} onClick={() => this.deleteOnePreView(photo)} /> //Este es el evento donde se ejecuta la animación
)}
```

De modo que el método `deleteOnePreView` quedaría así:

```
deleteOnePreView = (photoToRemove) => {
  if (window.confirm('Vas a eliminar esta foto, ¿estás seguro?')) {
    photoToRemove.style.animation = 'delete 300ms';
    photoToRemove.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
      this.setState({
        photosPreView: getPhotosPreviewsExcept(photoToRemove)
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Es verdad, podría acceder a `target.src` y removerlo del array "photosPreView". Pero también tengo el array "files" (donde están los archivos) del cual también debo eliminarlo. Y ya que no sé cómo comparar `target.url` contra el contenido del array "files", no se me ocurrió otra idea que recorrer "photosPreView" para conocer su índice y así eliminarlo de ambos arrays; porque intenté acceder a `target.index` pero la propiedad siempre es `undefined`. ¿Cómo encuentro la preView dentro del array files?, ¿o cómo hago para acceder a `target.index`?
¡Desde ya muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: Hice una adaptación de mi código al tuyo, utilizando onTransitionEnd; pero aún así sigue surgiendo ese problema donde hay fotos que no se animan, y por lo tanto no se ejecuta el `this.setState`. ¿Qué está ocurriendo?